# PyTorch for Object detection - Image augmentation

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

I am using PyTorch for object detection and refining an existing model (transfer learning) as described in the following link -
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

While different transformations are used for image augmentation (horizontal flip in this tutorial), the tutorial doesnt mention anything on transforming the bounding box/annotation to ensure they are in line with the transformed image. Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the training phase, the transforms are indeed applied on both images and targets, while loading the data. In the `PennFudanDataset` class, we have these two lines:

```
if self.transforms is not None:  
    img, target = self.transforms(img, target)
```

where `target` is a dictionary containing:

```
target = {}
target["boxes"] = boxes
target["labels"] = labels
target["masks"] = masks
target["image_id"] = image_id
target["area"] = area
target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd
```

`self.transforms()` in `PennFudanDataset` class is set to a list of transforms comprising `[transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Compose()]`, the return value from `get_transform()` while instantiating the dataset with:

```
dataset = PennFudanDataset('PennFudanPed', get_transform(train=True))
```

The transforms [`transforms.Compose()` comes from `T`, a *custom* transform](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/detection/transforms.py#L16) written for object detection task. Specifically, in the [`__call__` of `RandomHorizontalFlip()`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/detection/transforms.py#L30), we process both the *image* and *target* (e.g., mask, keypoints):

For the sake of completeness, I borrow the code from the github repo:

```
def __call__(self, image, target):
        if random.random() < self.prob:
            height, width = image.shape[-2:]
            image = image.flip(-1)
            bbox = target["boxes"]
            bbox[:, [0, 2]] = width - bbox[:, [2, 0]]
            target["boxes"] = bbox
            if "masks" in target:
                target["masks"] = target["masks"].flip(-1)
            if "keypoints" in target:
                keypoints = target["keypoints"]
                keypoints = _flip_coco_person_keypoints(keypoints, width)
                target["keypoints"] = keypoints
        return image, target
```

Here, we can understand how they perform the flipping on the *masks* and *keypoints* in accordance with the image.